# Port monitoring on GNU/Linux based NAT router

Tags: linux, monitoring, firewall, ip, tcp

I am using a Ubuntu machine as a NAT router. How can I find out the following:

- the ports on which the LAN machines are listening or communicating (both tcp and udp);
- which local machines have established connections with which WAN ip's on those ports;
- and the size of data that has been transfered on those ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to try [netstat-nat](http://tweegy.nl/projects/netstat-nat/)  I seem to remember using it when I had a Slackware box set up as a NAT-server.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo iftop`

`sudo netstat -ntlp`

`sudo tcpdump -i /dev/ethX`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try "lsof " with a combination of different flags one in particular "-i" , if you don't have the package , see that you install it, the data displayed is easily read and can give you a good insight about whats happening on your network.